# Monitor refresh rate getting reset

Tags: xorg, monitor

I am having an issue with my 144hz monitor. When I restart my PC the changes I have made to the refresh rate via the Nvidia X Server Settings panel get reset. Initially turning on Ubuntu I have 144hz enabled, but upon logging in it is reverted to 60hz.